# How to run my angularJs app into hosted server

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am new for angularJs development... I have successfully installed "yeoman" into my PC(I am using windows-7 64-bit system) and my app folder structure is:

- components
- images
- scripts
- styles
- views
- index.html etc...

I am using "grunt server" command for running my application in localhost, But my question is that.. suppose I want to upload my app into hosted server, So which files should I upload into server and how to run the app, Is there any option to run "grunt server" command into server.
So please give me some suggestion for this.

Comment: typically you'd use a program like Apache to host your project. Most "web hosts" have this built in, you simply upload to your "www" or "public_html" folder and it will work.

Comment: actually I have installed XAMPP. So if I want to use angular app with php then I need to copy angular app folder into xampp htdocs folder.. but currently my app folder is C:\Users\anil\app and my xampp folder is C:\xampp\htdocs so after copying app folder into htdocs.. grunt server will run???

Comment: You don't need grunt server, grunt server is just like Apache or XAMPP, but it's only for quick testing or working locally. It's not meant to be used for hosting your project. You would use XAMPP (which includes apache) for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `grunt` which builds a distributable version of your app into the `dist` folder. You then upload the contents of that folder to your preferred hosting provider.